# jQuery - Compare input to existing select optgroup options

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to loop through options in in a form select. They are separated into optgroups, which I think is where I'm having my problem, I just can't find the correct syntax.

The goal is to compare the `.val()` entered with the `.text()` of options in the list. If there is a match, turn the text red, if not, turn it green.

If I enter an invalid id instead of `sreportname` here: `$("#sreportname option")` then the text always turns green. with `sreportname` entered, nothing happens. I'm at a loss.

here is my form:

```
<form>
    <select name="sreportname" id="sreportname" class="form-control">
        <option value="zrxqy">--Choose a Report--</option>
        <option value="newReport">--Create a New Report--</option>
        <optgroup label="General Reports">
            <option>Abandoned Mines</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="TPS Reports">
            <option>Farm</option>
            <option>Store</option>
            <option>Chicken Coops</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="newReportName" name="newReportName">
</form>
```

and here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var exists = false;
    $("#newReportName").keyup(function () {
        $("#sreportname option").each(function () {
            if ($(this).text() == content) {
                exists = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if(exists) {
            $(this).css("color", "red");
        } else {
            $(this).css("color", "green");
        }
    });
});
```

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/18qr2ae9/1/). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close.  You simply need to get the `content` variable from `newReportName`.  Also, move `exists` inside the `keyup` function:

```js
$("#newReportName").keyup(function () {
  var exists = false;
  var content= $(this).val();
  $("#sreportname option").each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() == content) {
      exists = true;
      return false;
    }
  });
  if(exists) {
    $(this).css("color", "red");
  } else {
    $(this).css("color", "green");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <select name="sreportname" id="sreportname" class="form-control">
        <option value="zrxqy">--Choose a Report--</option>
        <option value="newReport">--Create a New Report--</option>
        <optgroup label="General Reports">
            <option>Abandoned Mines</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="TPS Reports">
            <option>Farm</option>
            <option>Store</option>
            <option>Chicken Coops</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="newReportName" name="newReportName">
</form>
```

Comment: Happens to us all : )